# line integral hard function to differentiate

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\int_\gamma \frac{(x^2+y^2-2)\,dx+(4y-x^2-y^2-2) \, dy}{x^2+y^2-2x-2y+2}$$

where $\gamma = 2\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ from $(2,0)$ to $(0,0)$.

I think it should be a shortcut to this problem that I cannot see , if that is not the case I will keep trying to simplify it .

Thnaks in advance

Comment: From my experience these complicated ones you can do it using greens theorem and hopefully get 0. Notice the hopefully

Comment: Yes but  taking the curl of the vector field is not simple.

Comment: If this differential form is exact, then the integral is just the difference between the values of the potential at the two points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete the squares in the denominator $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2$ and change the variables $x-1\mapsto x$ and $y-1\mapsto y$. You get the vector field
\begin{align}
&\left[\frac{x^2+2x+y^2+2y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{4y-x^2-2x-y^2-2y}{x^2+y^2}\right]=\\
&=\left[1+\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2},-1+\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}\right]-2\left[\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right].
\end{align}
The first term is conservative (with an easy potential), the second term has zero curl (easy to check).

P.S. Actually the second term has a potential too if you restrict you domain e.g. to the plain without the negative $y$-axis, but the potential is less obvious (easier to get in the polar coordinates).

Comment: What causes greens theorem not to work ? i mean i know two criterion now , the curve has to be closed and the vector field must be defined and differentiable in the region am integration over , is there something am missing ?

Comment: @Jacksoja Green's theorem works well, of course. The curl is zero, you can check it for the original field with some extra effort. Then due to singularity at  $(1,1)$ you have to pick a correct completion of the path - not along the $x$-axis, but along the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ centered at $(1,1)$ counterclockwise.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Let $I$ denote the integral. Note that the curve can be parameterized using curve using

$$x(t) = t$$
$$y(t) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)$$

for $0 \leq t \leq 2$

Thus, separate your integral into two different integrals:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 2}{x^2 + y^2 - 2x - 2y + 2} dx \qquad \mathrm{and} \qquad\int_\gamma \frac{4y - x^2 - y^2 - 2}{x^2 + y^2 - 2x - 2y + 2} dy$$

whose sum is equal to $I$.